# SpecFlow/NUnit/Selenium tests running from wrong PWD

Tags: unit-testing, directory, nunit, resharper

For a new project I am working on, my team and I are trying to get some Feature Tests set up using ReSharper 10, NUnit, SpecFlow, and Selenium.  We migrated a bunch of our old code from a known working project and got it to build without issue.

However, when we run our code, we keep getting the following error:

```
OneTimeSetUp: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\SomeApp\App_Data\SomeApp.db'.

Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
```

...This isn't right; if it's failing to find the `SomeApp.db` file, it should be failing from `C:\MyProjects\SomeApp\SomeApp.Web\App_Data\SomeApp.db`!

The relevant code in this case is in our TestSuite.cs class:

```
[Binding]
public class TestSuite
{
    private string _currentPath;
    private string _localFile;
    private string _websiteBinPath;
    private string _websiteDataPath;

    // Stuff...

    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTestRun()
    {
        _currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\";
        // Data:
        // <add key="TestWebsiteDataRelativePath" value="..\..\..\SomeApp.Web\App_Data\" />
        // <add key="TestWebsiteBinRelativePath" value="..\..\..\SomeApp.Web\bin\" />
        _websiteBinPath = Path.Combine(_currentPath, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestWebsiteBinRelativePath"]);
        _websiteDataPath = Path.Combine(_currentPath, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestWebsiteDataRelativePath"]);

        //removes the ../../../
        _websiteBinPath = Path.GetFullPath((new Uri(_websiteBinPath)).LocalPath);
        _websiteDataPath = Path.GetFullPath((new Uri(_websiteDataPath)).LocalPath);

        _localFile = _websiteDataPath + "SomeApp.db";

        DoStuffWithLocalFile();
    }

    // Stuff...
}
```

We set a breakpoint on the first executable line of code and stepped over code until `currentPath` had a value - the directory that `currentPath` had was `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs14\`!

We have already disabled Shadow Copy via the ReSharper options, and for extra measure I disabled MSTest support also from the ReSharper options.  Yet, the test project still will not operate out of `C:\MyProjects\SomeApp\SomeApp.FeatureTest\bin\Debug` directory.

**Question:** 
In what way can I get my feature test project to run from `C:\MyProjects\SomeApp\SomeApp.FeatureTest\bin\Debug`, and *not* out of `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs14\`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you use NUnit 3.0? If so, please refer to [NUnit 3.0 Breaking-Changes page](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Breaking-Changes):

> CurrentDirectory No longer set to the directory containing the test
>   assembly. Use TestContext.TestDirectory to locate that directory.

Comment: This was what I needed to do.  FYI, the call above uses `System.IO.Directory` to get the PWD, but this seems to be the better way to go.